# 8 y/o cat is not eating or drinking, is not playing, is walking slow, and lays in the corner of our spare bedroom

Tags: cats

Our younger cat (she is 8-1/2) started doing this about 2 months ago.  We took her to the vet and the emergency vet three times.  They took x-rays and did an ultrasound and found nothing. She barely eats and drinks anything and has lost quite a bit of weight. I know she is not using the litter box much. Her coats looks terrible. She lays in the corner of our spare bedroom.  Shes comes out occasionally.  I am pretty sure she is hungry.  She follows me into the kitchen, sits and looks up at me and meows, and smacks her lips. But when I put food down, she goes over to it, looks at is and walks away.  She may take a few licks, but that is about it.  I have purchased one of every brand of cat food I can find and does not appear to have interest in any of them.    I was thinking about buying kitten "milk" at the pet store and trying to force feed her with an eyedropper but I'm not sure how well that will work.  I am at my wits end.  I don't know what else to do for her.

Comment: you need to take the cat to the vet right now or it will die.stay away from the net and get your cat to the VET RIGHT NOW.

Comment: If possible, take her to another vet but bring the findings and diagnoses of her previous examinations. Her condition is critical and she will die if the cause isn't treated.

Comment: Agree with taking your cat to a different vet IMMEDIATELY. In fact, I'm no vet, but if that's really all they did, then basically said, "I just have no idea," then I question the quality of the first vet. Shouldn't they be doing bloodwork if they don't know? If the cat's not eating or drinking, shouldn't they be giving it an iv to at least get it hydrated? Were neither of these things seriously never suggested?

Comment: Forgot to mention that bloodwork was also done and was normal.  I have taken her to the vet at least 3 times plus the emergency bet twice.  Sub-q fluids have been given.  I don't think a different vet would be the answer.  They would just run the same tests with the same results.  I have full confidence in our vet and the emergency vet.  I am taking her back tonight for more Sub-q fluids and medication to stimulate her appetite.  Hopefully that works.

Comment: Hi Cynthia, your cat is clearly unwell so if the vets you've taken her to haven't been able to reach a diagnosis or at least move towards one, I implore you to follow the advice of Elmy and Kai and seek a review from a different vet. Unfortunately there's not a lot more that we can suggest here. I'm surprised that a cat that's malnourished would have bloodwork that is described as normal. Has anything in her environment changed that may have upset her? I also assume the vet has checked she has no dental problems?

Comment: @Cynthia Could this be a case of slow poisoning? Have you changed anything in your home at the time her behavior changed? Changed cleaning products, pet food, air refresheners, house plants or anything like that? Cats are very vulnerable to many substances that do no harm to humans or other pets and they can be poisoned by walking over a floor cleaned with a harmfull substance.

Answer (score 1):

This is something a vet needs to look at **immediately**.

This is not something this community can help you with. Don't use StackExchange as a way to avoid what is clearly an issue worth investigating medically.